# Is there a standard 3d vector class in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, profiling

In an existing project, I see a class Vector_3d, templated, with the usual operations for vectors (in the sense of algebra). After profiling, I noticed that a large amount of the time is spent in this class.

I was wondering if there was a well-known implementation of such a basic concept as a 3d vector in C++. Indeed, it might be easier to use a good implementation of the vector instead of trying to optimize this one.

Edit:
This is in a context of a geometrical representation of some objects. But it is independent from any visualization. I will see if there is a way of avoiding to call the various methods too often. And I will have a look at the proposed packages.

Comment: What kind for project are you involved in? If it's related to 3D rendering you might have luck in using a well established real-time rendering package.

Comment: It can be the case that you can not avoid this fact. Maybe you should add the keyword "inline" to one of the often used functions. For example: raytracers use many funclions like the cross-product very often and it can not be avoided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no much room for improvement in a 3d vector class (basically, dot / cross products are fairly easy, matrix multiplication as well).
If so much time is spent in that class, maybe your code using it is flawed. Have you checked against

- copy vs references
- wrong association (like multiply matrix then all vectors by the resulting matrix, rather than all vectors by the chain of matrices)

I know that there is [QVector3D](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qvector3d.html) in Qt, that might help you (by the way, they got Vector 2D and 4D as well for common 3D geometry operations)

Answer (score 4):

Dave Eberly's http://www.geometrictools.com/ is a great resource for those types of classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).  Plus it's header-only and has built-in vectorization support.

Answer (score 0):

Boost::QVM could be also an option: http://boostorg.github.io/qvm/